# Java NIO allocateDirect upfront or copy before syscall

Tags: java, nio

I'm designing a server application using Java NIO. I'm trying to decide if allocateDirect per client is a bad idea. I did a benchmark and with a small (less than a KB) buffer the performance difference is negligible (compared to a `HeapByteBuffer`).

Should I just stop overthinking it and use a `DirectByteBuffer` per client?

I will be allocating two buffers after a client is accepted. Now obviously before creating all that garbage, IP checks for flooding will be done.

When the SocketChannel.read/write method is called it will allocate a temp `DirectByteBuffer` and copy the `HeapByteBuffer` to it before sending it off to the OS.

Is it better to let the read/write method do that conversion?

My thoughts are that while I'm working on the buffers (doing put/get calls) (constructing a response into the output buffer) it would be better to do all that on a `HeapByteBuffer` and then do the conversion to a `DirectByteBuffer` when the buffer is complete and ready to be written to the socket.

Unless doing put/get calls on a `DirectByteBuffer` is not much slower than a `HeapByteBuffer`. The idea here is that sure a single put call on a `DirectByteBuffer` is not a big deal, but when constructing a full response each individual put call can add up overall because each call requires crossing the JNI barrier. When if you just have a `HeapByteBuffer` and then the conversion happens during the SocketChanne.write the JNI barrier is only crossed once.